# How to get the instance of BrowserWindow that called an event?

Tags: electron

**Example**

You have multiple BrowserWindows opened and stored on an array of BrowserWindows, you want to know which window called the close event so you can remove that specific BrowserWindow from the array.

```
window.on('close', () => {
   // Get the instance of the window that called this event
})
```

**How?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `event.sender` its type `WebContents` you can't compare it with a `BrowserWindow`, only if you compare the `event.sender` with `BrowserWindow.webContents` property, but I guess that wouldn't provide an unique identification. A workaround to that would be comparing `event.sender.id` with `window.id`

```
window.on ('close', (event) => {
    // Use event.sender to get the instance of the window that called this event
    console.log (event.sender.id === window.id); // -> true
});
```

Comment: I am curious why `event.sender` even exists, I use typscript and althought BrowserWindow has many overrides of method on, the first parameter  of the callback is always event of type Event, which doe *not* contain sender at all. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

[BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#class-browserwindow) is an [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter); as such, the window's instance method `on` returns an `event` parameter in the callback function, from which you can access the window's instance by using the `event.sender` property.

```
window.on ('close', (event) => {
    // Use event.sender to get the instance of the window that called this event
    console.log (event.sender instanceof BrowserWindow); // -> true
    console.log (event.sender === window); // -> true
});
```

Comment: but `event.sender` its type `WebContents`, how can it be `===` to `BrowserWindow`? `BrowserWindow` has a property called `webContents`, but would this provide a unique identification?

Comment: This is odd... I tested the above code in one of my app and it does work flawlessly but with only one main window... I added  `console.log (event.sender instanceof BrowserWindow)` and it returns `true` too... Just out of curiosity, how did you get the type `WebContents` of `event.sender`?

Comment: Maybe is because I'm using TypeScript, any ways, thanks for your help, without it I wouldn't discover the `event.sender` and `event.sender.id`, so... many thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to close, you could do this:

```
window.on ('close', (_event) => {
    _event.sender.close();
});
```

The `event.sender` is of type `WebContents` which means you can do the following.
You don't need to have an array of BrowserWindows:

```
window.on ('close', (_event) => {
    const thatWindow = new BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(_event.sender);
    _event.sender?.close();
});
```

With there, you can do anything that is possible with such a `BrowserWindow`

See also:
[Documentation - BrowserWindow.fromWebContents()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#browserwindowfromwebcontentswebcontents)